Assembly: Difference between JNA and JL
I am new to assembly. I was checking out the conditional jumps and noticed that both jna and jl work similarly.
Here's the code I have written using jl and jna:
; using jl
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'A'
loop:
  int 0x10
  inc al
  cmp al, 'Z'
  jl loop

jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa

; using jna
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'A'
loop:
  int 0x10
  inc al
  cmp al, 'Z'
  jna loop

jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa

What's the exact difference between the two?

JL is used when the data is signed, whereas JNA is used when the data is unsigned.  You won't notice a difference between the two if you stick to smallish positive numbers.


I was checking out the conditional jumps and noticed that both jna and jl work similarly.

Similarly to some extent, but already your two examples prove that you cannot substitute one for the other, not even when the values that are involved happen to be "smallish positive numbers".
Your first program (jl) displays "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY" while your second program (jna) displays "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" (adding the "Z").
Big difference between jl and jna
In the first program the loop continues for as long as AL is smaller than 90 (ASCII code for "Z"), so this excludes "Z" itself.
In the second program however, the loop continues for as long as AL is not bigger than 90 (ASCII code for "Z"), so this includes "Z" itself because obviously 90 is not bigger than 90.
A perfectly valid replacement would have been to substitute jnge for jl (if you don't need the "Z"), or to substitute jbe for jna (if you do want the "Z").
In general
You should always know whether the numbers involved are signed or unsigned. As an example, ASCII codes are to be considered unsigned quantities.
When signed numbers are involved, then the relationship between them is expressed by the words less, equal, and greater.
For unsigned numbers, the relationship between them is governed by the terms below, equal, and above.




smaller (<)
same (=)
bigger (>)




signed numbers
less  jl / jnge
equal je
greater jg / jnle


unsigned numbers
below jb / jnae
equal je
above ja / jnbe




Could do with a mention of jl being equivalent to jnge respectively jbe and jna

There are multiple duplicates with good answers.  If you think there's anything to add to them, you should post this answer on one of those Q&As.  (I closed this question as a duplicate of some of the major ones.)  Hrm, actually this question is different because of the off-by-one error from using jna (aka jbe) instead of just jb vs. jl.

IDK if that warrants reopening, that's basically a separate problem that would also exist with jng vs. jl, unrelated to signed vs. unsigned branch conditions, which I think was what the OP was intending to ask about.  Maybe it's interesting to have an answer about that off-by-one end condition and different ways to end loops?  Future readers might have a hard time finding it, but at least we'd know where to link it.
